# `return false` in an event handler attached by addEventListener or element.on*

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener, preventdefault

Right let’s get this out the way first. Yes, I want to hide the context menu. No, I’m not trying to prevent someone lifting content off my page. Its intended use is input for an in-browser game and it will be limited to a specific area on the webpage.

Moving from the ideological to the technical...

```
var mouse_input = function (evt) {
    // ...
    return false;
}

document.onmousedown = mouse_input; // successful at preventing the menu.
document.addEventListener('mousedown', mouse_input, true); // unsuccessful
```

Could someone explain to me why the `addEventListener` version is unable to stop the context menu from firing? The only difference I was able to see in *Safari*'s *Web Inspector* was that `document.onmousedown` had a `isAttribute` value that was true whilst the `addEventListener` version had the same value as false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So my unfruitful search suddenly became fruitful.

```
var mouse_input = function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
}

document.addEventListener('contextmenu', mouse_input, false);
```

Works for *Safari*, *Firefox*, *Opera*. `preventDefault()` stops the usual actions from happening. I had to change the event that was listened for to accommodate for *Safari* and it is more logical anyway. Further information: functions that implement [EventListener](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-EventListener) shouldn’t return values so `return false` had no effect.

Comment: Yes, that's the way to do it. It won't work in IE, though: in IE, you'll need to use `attachEvent` and set `window.event.returnValue` to `false`.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I’m targeting browsers with `<canvas>` support and fortunately I believe IE9 has both that and `addEventListener`.

Comment: Yes, that's true. Fair enough.

Answer (score 4):

To explain the difference .. `element.onmousedown = somefunction;` is an absolute assignment; you are *replacing* the event handler on the element. `element.addEventListener(...)` is, as the name implies, *adding* a handler in addition to any handler(s) already attached for the event.